# Golang pass JSON object to a function

Tags: json, selenium, go, proxy

This is regarded the [Selenium Web driver](https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium) but I think it is not quite important.

I can set the browser name

```
caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "firefox"}
wd, _ := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "")
```

But for "proxy" ie:

```
caps := selenium.Capabilities{"proxy": "http://1.2.3.4:999"}
wd, _ := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "")
```

I have to pass a [JSON Proxy Object](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#Proxy_JSON_Object) which I absolutely have no idea how to create... I searched there and there, but still could not figure... Is it kind of struct? Or map.. or what... :-(

Comment: Have you tried `selenium.Capabilities{"proxy": map[string]interface{}{"httpProxy": "http://1.2.3.4:999"}}`?

Comment: Yes, that worked, how did you know? :-) Thanks a lot!
Working line line this: 
`caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "firefox", "proxy": map[string]interface{}{"proxyType": "manual", "httpProxy": "218.97.194.214:80"}}` 
Ah its, seems written in there [json and go](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in the comment, you can use the form

```
selenium.Capabilities{
    "proxy": map[string]interface{}{
        "httpProxy": "http://1.2.3.4:999",
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Unstructured JSON is usually (un)marshalled through `map[string]interface{}`, and the type [`selenium.Capabilities`](https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium#Capabilities) is in fact just a `map[string]interface{}`.

See also: [JSON and Go](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).